# how to ls -*.apk?

Tags: bash, shell, adb

i ma writing a java program to run a sh script. to install many apk in many devices in the mean time. but i have some problem with my script and i don't know why.
the code of the script is

```
#!/bin/bash

checkParameter() {

        echo "$1"
        if [ -d $1 ]; then
            echo "$1 est bien un repertoire"
        else 
            echo "Vérifier si vous avez bien séléctionné un reperoire"
        fi

    }
    # pour chercher les devices connectés
 devices(){
 adb devices > devices.txt
    }

 install(){
    echo "Debut de l'installation"



         a=`ls $1 *.apk | wc -l`

    for SERIAL in $(adb devices | tail -n +2 | cut -sf 1);
    do  

        echo "le nombre des Applications à installer $a"

        for APKLIST in $(ls $1 *.apk);
        do
            if [ $a -eq 0 ] 
            then
                break;
            fi

            echo "Installatroning $APKLIST on $SERIAL"
            #adb -s $SERIAL install  $1/$APKLIST &
        #adb bugreport > bug.txt
        done
        $a = `expr $a - 1`
    done
 echo "La fin de l'Installation "
 }




    checkParameter
    devices
    install

echo 'exit normally'

exit 0
```

i have a problem that some instruction unkown and the script is never finished. it is running all the time until i press a key

```
 a=`ls $1 *.apk | wc -l` unkown
```

Output:

```
est bien un repertoire
Debut de l'installation
./codes/adb.sh: ligne 24: =3 : commande introuvable
le nombre des Applications à installer 
ls: impossible d'accéder à *.apk: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
expr: erreur de syntaxe
./codes/adb.sh: ligne 41: = : commande introuvable
La fin de l'Installation 
exit normally
```

Comment: When posting code, please fix your identation.  A mix of tabs and spaces may not display the same as in your editor.

Comment: Quand tu lances un script qui génère des erreurs, lance le comme ça : `LANG=C ./script` pour avoir les erreurs en Anglais =)

Answer (score 6):

The following statement is incorrect:

```
$a = `expr $a - 1`
```

There should be no spaces around the `=`. Change it to:

```
a=`expr $a - 1`
```

Alternatively, you can also write it as:

```
((a--))
```